# simple shell script question. please give me advise

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i have a question about simple shell script.

this is the source code of **rand.sh** below

```sh
#!/bin/bash

n=$(( RANDOM % 100 ))
if [[ n -eq 42 ]]; then
    echo "Something went wrong"
    >&2 echo "The error was using magic numbers"
    exit 1
fi
echo "Everything went accrding to plan"
```

and i'm going to make a new shell script, let me call it **quiz.sh**.

quiz.sh should loop until n==42. if n==42, save the stdout("Something went wrong") and stderr("The error was using magic numbers")

and it finally terminated with printing out those stdout,stderr and Total execution count.

here is my **quiz.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cnt=0
while [[ "${n}" -ne 42 ]]
do
    (( cnt = "${cnt}"+1 ))
    source ./rand.sh &> error.txt
done
cat error.txt
echo "${cnt}"
```

but this is not working. because of  `exit 1` in **rand.sh**, the program is terminated before executing `cat` and `echo` which is at the end two line.

how can i fix it?? please let me know!

Comment: `if [[ n -eq 42 ]];` `n`  is a string, it's not a number. `how can i fix it?` fix what exactly? what do you _want_ to happen? Is this bad that the program terminates, it seems like you expected that.

Comment: @KamilCuk i mean, i want to execute whole quiz.sh. but the program is terminated at `source ./rand.sh &> error.txt` because if n==42, rand.sh is terminate with returning code 1. i want to make happen `cat error.txt` and `echo "${cnt}"` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to make happen cat error.txt and echo "${cnt}" as well

Run the loop in a subshell

```
(
while something; do
    something
    exit 1 # exits only from the subshell
done
)
```

Note: parent shell doesn't access/inherit child process environment. So `cnt` is going to be empty in parent shell. Transfer it some other way.

```
(
cnt=0
while ((n != 42)); do
    ((cnt++))
    echo "$cnt" > cntfile.txt
    # >& is deprecated
    source myrand > error.txt 2>&1
done
)
cnt=$(<cntfile.txt)
cat error.txt
echo "$cnt"
```

Reference [Bash manual command grouping](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html).

Comment: thanks for your advice cuk. your idea works for me. i can see `error.txt` and cnt as a output now.

Answer (score 0):

As KamilCuk pointed out correctly, you should use `$n` instead of `n`.

Furthermore, I personally would add that using `source ./rand.sh &> error.txt` is kind of weird in this case. If you want to run it as a background process, use:

```sh
./rand.sh &> error.txt &
wait $!  # $! is the pid
```

Otherwise, just make a function out of it:

```
#!/bin/bash

function myrand {
    n=$(( RANDOM % 100 ))
    if [[ n -eq 42 ]]; then
        echo "Something went wrong"
        >&2 echo "The error was using magic numbers"
        return 1
    fi
    echo "Everything went accrding to plan"
    return 0
}


cnt=0
while [[ "${n}" -ne 42 ]]
do
    (( cnt = "${cnt}"+1 ))
    myrand() &> error.txt
done
cat error.txt
echo "${cnt}"
```

p.s. code not tested, but I guess it works.

Comment: thanks for your helpful code. there's one thing to change `myrand() &> error.txt` -> `myrand &> error.txt` but it was perfect enough. but unfortunately, i had to solve this problem without fixing **rand.sh** which mean i can't change `exit`->`return`. thank you!

Comment: In that case using a child process should work. Please that note that there's a difference between sourcing it and a child process. Sourcing it includes the source of the script into your own, while using a child executes a new process. I find child processes easier to use and it is less likely that unforeseen errors will occur. However, you should play with `wait` a little bit. Glad I could help :-)